# How to make window size fixed?

Tags: vim, editor, nerdtree

When i am using nerdtree to browse my file, it always happened to make NerdTree to resize to full fill current window, and i don't know how to change to its default width. Is there a method to make the size of nerdtree window fixed? Or reset the window size to default?

Comment: I believe some emacser have good skill at vim ^_^.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it is strange that you have this issue, but the widow width seems to be set via `g:NERDTreeWinSize` variable and should be 31 (you can see this in the plugin source (see line 44 here: https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree/blob/master/plugin/NERD_tree.vim)

obviously, setting this variable in the source script will work, but there should be better ways of setting it in your `.vimrc`.

have you tried toggling the nerdtree window using `A`? does that set the correct window size?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But what do you mean by toggling the nerdtree window using A?

Comment: thanks.. while in the nerdtree window typing 'Shift-A' will first maximize the window, then pressening 'Shift-A' again will reset the NerdTree window to the correct size. @FrankCheng, try out the above.. and let use know if it works..

Answer (score 0):

You can set the NERDTree window size, e.g. to 26, by adding the following to your .vimrc file:

```
let NERDTreeWinSize=26
```

Answer (score 0):

Internally NERDTree uses [winfixwidth](https://neovim.io/doc/user/options.html#'winfixwidth'). Another useful option is [equalalways](https://neovim.io/doc/user/options.html#'equalalways'), if turned off, disables automatic window resizing when creating or closing windows.